# HttpInterceptor calling another service inside an interceptor and waiting for response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I have to call another service in an interceptor if a certain condition is met and I want the original service to wait until the new service will complete. My first solution was using tap:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, options: any, next: HttpServiceHandler)
  : Observable <HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req, options).pipe(
      tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.ok && event.body) {
          const productsToGet = [...]
          if (* condition *) {
            const resourceService = this.injector.get(ResourceService);
            return resourceService.getProducts(productsToGet);
          }
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

But it obviously didn't work like I wanted to because original method finished before getProducts was completed. Then I used solution from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656992/httpinterceptor-change-response-body-based-on-value-from-other-observable) with switchMap:

```
return next.handle(req, options).pipe(
  filter((event: HttpEvent<any>) => (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.ok && event.body)),
  switchMap((event: HttpResponse<any>) => {
    const productsToGet = [...]
    if (* condition *) {
      const resourceService = this.injector.get(ResourceService);
      return resourceService.getProducts(productsToGet).pipe(
        mapTo(event)
      )
    } else {
      return of(event);
    }
  })
);
```

But now I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) EmptyError: no elements in sequence.

Can you tell me if my solution is valid and what should I do to make it work?

Full error stack:

```
> Error: Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at zone.js:913
    at ZoneDelegate.push.../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26754)
    at ZoneDelegate.push.../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push.../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push.../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1693)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the if condition is and how it works ? Also, which line is throwing the error ?

Comment: Condition checks if productsToGet array is not empty, because it depends on the event.body.
I edited original post with full stack of an error.

Comment: rather than ```switchMap``` ```exhaustMap``` is a better operator here as it will wait till your inner observable exhausts

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! But unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve my problem since i am still getting that EmptyError :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was a problem with filter. Observables from responses that have been filtered out weren't returned from interceptor. Therefore i removed filter and added it inside switchMap, returning of(event) for responses that doesn't meet filter conditions.